# Rails VideoJS swf-Flash-Fallback asset_path

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html5-video, asset-pipeline

I am currently trying to embed videoJS in my rails-app, which works fine as long as I don't have to use the flash-fallback, e.g. in Firefox. I am hosting videoJS locally. Here is what I have so far in my JavaScript:

```
videojs.options.techOrder = ['flash'];
videojs.options.flash.swf = "#{asset_path(video-js/video-js.swf)}";
```

I am using techOrder to force flash for the time beeing. If I open my page now in Firefox all I get is

```
GET http://localhost:3000/path/to/site/videos#{asset_path(video-js/video-js.swf)}
```

The error message, that the video is not supported disappears and the playbutton appears. The leads me to belive, that the flashplugin is not loaded (especially since I think that the GET does not look right). Any hint as to where my error is, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use gem [`js_assets`](https://github.com/kavkaz/js_assets)

In your application.js

```
//= require app_assets
```

This directive adds the method asset_path in the global scope.

Add to filter files `*.swf`. To do this, add initizlizer:

```
# config/initializers/js_assets.rb

JsAssets::List.allow << '*.swf'
```

To get the path to the file `video-js.swf` depending on the environment

```
videojs.options.flash.swf = asset_path("video-js/video-js.swf");
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest https://github.com/seanbehan/videojs_rails actually puts this in your video.js already.  No need to add it separately.  I am assuming you're using this from your title.